# Static Google Maps don't work for my case

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've 2 simple images:

1. Pure map pin: http://platform.docplanner.com/img/general/icons/map-pin.png
2. Promo map pin: http://platform.docplanner.com/img/general/icons/map-pin-calendar.png

Both of them are accessible by above links.

And what I'm going to do is simple two versions of map.
One with simple pins, and second with promo pins.

`<img src="{url with params and pure pin icon}" alt=""/>
<img src="{url with params and promo pin icon}" alt=""/>`

The problem is that first case works correctly, and 2nd one no (400 error from Google - http://take.ms/pPamV).

Here is jsfiddle with code: http://jsfiddle.net/qp4jdhL0/1/
In both cases I've used same lat & lng (20 per map) in params for Google Static Map request.

Have You any idea what's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the length of the URL.

Google Maps API will allow up to 2048 characters (*the big one is 2171 while the small one is 1991*)

Quote from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits)

> **URL Size Restriction**
>
> Static Map URLs are restricted to 2048 characters in size.

But you can reduce the url length by not defining the icon for each marker. If you define one it will be applied to all following markers.

So just use it once and follow it by coordinate pairs separated by `|`

---

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=245x272&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://platform.docplanner.com/img/general/icons/map-pin-calendar.png||52.1598892,21.0696316|52.2009163,20.9666195|52.2870255,21.0283909|50.2554169,19.0244465|50.3023148,18.7893543|51.7696419,19.4822693|54.3800964,18.5857487|51.2643013,15.5582724|50.30476,18.9447422|51.7388725,19.4120331|52.2514076,20.9978237|52.2356453,21.1359806|54.3785172,18.6070824|51.8151283,19.4298782|51.2461815,22.5612831|52.2870255,21.0283909|50.0593109,19.926136|51.7768898,19.4775219|51.6970253,17.4467545|50.0227585,19.9021263

Length is now reduced to 595 chars.

Comment: Hmm another one case. What if I want to mix 2 solutions?? So: some pure icons, some promo icons?? The only way to do it is for example make shorter URL to pin images??

Comment: You can define a new marker so that the subsequent coordinates will use that. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/z24wpue0/ or more clear at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/z24wpue0/1/